# How can I get the Launch dynamic link in Unity?

Tags: unity, firebase

I have integrated firebase dynamic link sdk in my app and it is working perfectly fine,

I can generate dynamic links, and when clicked on them if the app is not installed it redirects me to the playstore and if installed open up the link in app.

My question is how can I get that generated link when I open the app through it, I just could not able to find anything in docs

the code I am using to listen for link clicks is as follows

```
void Start()
{
    DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
}

// Display the dynamic link received by the application.
private void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
    Debug.LogFormat("Received dynamic link {0}", dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString);
    // Above line gets me the original base link,
    // But I want the link which I clicked
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the code as below:

```
void Start()
{
    DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
}

private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
{
    DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
}
```